# How to change the values of an axis in a ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

So, I have a plot similar to this one.

```
x = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 19]
y = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 19]

ListLinePlot[{y/Max[y], x/Max[x]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 19}, {0.4, 1}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {"97", Red}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Bias Coefficient", "Normalized Value"}]
```

What I would like to do is to change the values shown in the x axis to the normalized  "Normalized Value" that were used to generate the lists in the first place (the values of X and Y at the sample code are dummies), which I would like to input by hand.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you can replace the PlotRange option with the option `DataRange -> {0, 1}`?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you want, it's possible that such code

```
x = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 19];
y = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 19];
z = {Table[{i/Length[y], y[[i]]/Max[y]}, {i, 1, Length[y]}], 
   Table[{i/Length[x], x[[i]]/Max[x]}, {i, 1, Length[x]}]};
ListLinePlot[z, PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {"97", Red}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Bias Coefficient", "Normalized Value"}]
```

[image: fig1]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a great comment, I would also use `DataRange`, as it is less extra code, than defining your own x-vector [as did Alex](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179433/2036). However, the code of Alex allows you to do also many other things.

```
x = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 19]
y = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 19]

ListLinePlot[{y/Max[y], x/Max[x]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.4, 1}}, 
 DataRange -> {0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {"97", Red}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Bias Coefficient", "Normalized Value"}]
```

[image]

Note, that I also updated the `PlotRange`.

But it is little bit unclear what you wanted to do. As you have labeled your two vectors `x` and `y`, perhaps this was your goal?

```
x = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 19]
y = RandomReal[{0.5, 1}, 19]

ListPlot[Transpose[{x/Max[x], y/Max[y]}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.4, 1}}, DataRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {"97", Red}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Normalized Value", "Bias Coefficient"}]
```

[image]